# Gauss Law and Potentials

Tags: electromagnetism

> The infinite plane $z = 0$ is earthed and the infinite plane $z=d$ carries a charge of $\sigma$
>   per unit area. Find the electrostatic potential between the planes.

I have tried to compute the electric field between the two plates;the field points vertically downwards between the plates and has magnitude $\frac{\sigma}{ε_0}$, by Gauss' law. But above the plates, the field points vertically upwards with equal magnutide.

By symmetry should the magnitude of the total field be  $\frac{\sigma}{2ε_0}$ and hence is the potential 
$\frac{\sigma}{2ε_0}\times z$ ? Or do I only take into account the component vertically downwards?

Comment: "But above the plates, [...]" You're explicitly told not to care about above the plates. The problem asks you to find an answer for between the plates.

Comment: Is the answer $\dfrac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\times z$ (for $0<z<d$)?

Comment: so is my first answer correct? I just don't understand how we can ignore the top half?

Comment: Someone please help!

Comment: Does the lower plate also create an electric field?